# How do I launch an activity in android app (without Icon) using a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am running Android 4.4 on my device and am trying to develop a hidden screen which will be triggered only on entering a keycode from the dialer. To this end, I declared the manifest file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.hiddenscreen">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".HiddenInfoScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".SecretKeyInputReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="0">
            <!-- Intent for new outgoing call -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Now in my receiver "SecretKeyInputReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver" I am reading the intent extras, to evaluate the number and then display the activity.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")){
        // Intercepted out going call. Now check if it matches the apps secret code.
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if(null == extras)
            return;
        String numDialled = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if(numDialled.equals("00000")){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.setClass(context, HiddenInfoScreen.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            setResultData(null);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Now after the activity is installed, there is no icon in the launcher (as expected) but dialing "00000" from the dialpad, does not display the activity. Yes, I tried setting other number of different lengths as well, and they did not work. Please help me with this. 
I have also tried the approach of adding the icon to the launcher and using PackageManager to remove the icon once the activity is launched.

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But this means that the activity can no longer be launched even via the keycode.

Your inputs would be valued. I am targetting the application to run above Android 3.1+ and so using BootComplete to launch the application's activity would be no use.

Comment: why u need broadcastu can launch from intent also right ..mark that activity u wanna open frmo differen package as exported

Comment: Can u please share a sample ?

Comment: can u come on stackoverflow chat?

Comment: Sorry just saw the notification. Am on chat now.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o